# Chrome Showing all requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an account in a website that I can parse some information I want from them, but just when my browser is on their page, if I close the page I can't parse info anymore (i.e. the link I am using to get information will just return blank).

But as they have this callback protection, I must stay logged for being able to access it.

I tried analyzing the website using the chrome developer bar. But it won't show any request, however, the bytes sent get increased every couple seconds, as I think this is the callback, but chrome doesn't show as a request.

https://streamable.com/asxzp

What can I do to show this request so I can try to fake it using curl, for example?

Comment: I just remembered Burp Suite. I will try to use their proxy to see if I can see all the requests.

Comment: This may be a websocket. Click on network -> filter for WS and click on it, there will be requests inside it if its used

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But there is nothing on the WS tab

Comment: Did you leave a filter on in the network tab? also, if all else fails, try wireshark.

Comment: There are no filters, I will try wireshark, thank you so much @TimothyGroote!